# Missing color when plotting a raster

Tags: r, plot, colors, raster, r-raster

When I try plotting a Raster object, R gives a plot without colors.

```
library(raster)
r.base <- raster(ncol=40,nrow=40,xmn=-74,xmx=-34,ymn=-34,ymx=6)
wgs<-"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
projection(r.base) <- wgs
set.seed(0)
values(r.base) <- runif(ncell(r.base))
plot(r.base)
```

Code runs on a Windows server with R3.3.0, resulting in: 
[Plot without color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY9Ht.jpg)

On a private computer the plot funciton works fine, resulting the intented output:
[Plot with color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmAM4.jpg)

Comment: I get the plot with color. Not sure how to replicate your problem.

Comment: Right, it cannot be a coding mistake. But what could it be then?

Comment: See the note here about problems with RDP and rasters on Windows: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rasterImage.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if the colour quality of your computer graphic card is set to the highest, for example, 32-bit. Lower quality (16-bit) may result in no colour in the plots produced by the package "raster".